# Could the Bruce Lee scene in "Once Upon a Time in Hollywood" have been imagined?

Tags: analysis, once-upon-a-time-in-hollywood

The infamous Bruce Lee scene with Cliff Booth is framed as a thought sequence as Cliff is fixing a roof antenna. Although presumably the scene was a flashback, the framing actually makes it indiscernible from an *imagined scene* i.e. a daydream.

The way I interpreted the scene was not "this is what I remember happening," but rather "this is what would probably would happen if I went back to working on movie sets, and it's why I'm fixing roof antennae instead of being on sets."

This certainly fits better with the hyper-unrealistic portrayal of Bruce Lee, since it's a hypothetical sequence.

My question is what, from the movie only (not Tarantino interviews or anything off-screen), indicates that this sequence was actually a flashback and not a dream sequence?

n.b. The scene directly preceding explains that Cliff would have trouble landing a job with this particular movie director for some reason. There are two interpretations of this with the Bruce Lee scene in context. One interpretation is "it's unlikely I would get that job because I dented the car sparring with Bruce Lee" while another is "it's unlikely I would get that job because if I did, I would probably do something like dent his car sparring with Bruce Lee." I don't feel that the movie definitively states which is the right interpretation.